# Where to to put ts2591.mpy so that raspberry pi can utilize lux sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

First Post, so please be gentle.

I am trying to run a lux meter on a raspberry pi 3 B+.  The lux meter is Ts2591, that according to adafruit can be run by installing circuit python files.  I have been following the instructions and am having trouble with where to put the ts2591.mpy file.  I assume .mpy stands for python module.  The website states to place it in the lib file.  I have placed in in the python 3.7 lib file and the raspberry pi lib file, but I keep getting a 'cannot find module' error.  If it turns out it has to go to a root file system, I am not sure where that is.  I don't see a way to ask adafruit directly.

Here is the phrasing from the web site:

> **Before continuing make sure your board's lib folder or root filesystem has the adafruit_tsl2591.mpy, and adafruit_bus_device files and folders copied over.**

Answer (score 0):

The Adafruit ts2591 library is meant to be used with [CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.org/), (which is like a fork of [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/)). Both CircuitPython and MicroPython have built-in support for the hardware generally found on microcontrollers, like the UART, I2C and SPI communication buses and things like ADC's and switching hardware pins on and off.

Out of the box, this code won't work with "standard" python. For one thing, regular Python doesn't have built-in I2C support. The raspberry pi has Python modules to support its special hardware, but those are different (have a different API) from the ones in CircuitPython.

Basically you have a couple of options.

1. You can use the [adafruit blinka](https://pypi.org/project/Adafruit-Blinka/) compatibility layer and then the adafruit_tsl2591 module.
2. You can port the tsl2591 code to run on the raspberry Pi. Luckily, this has already been done: [maxlklaxl/python-tsl2591](https://github.com/maxlklaxl/python-tsl2591). Download that from github or [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/python-tsl2591/#files).

In general, since you can read the CircuitPython code, porting that to another platform with another I2C library isn't too hard.

Comment: I pursued the github path and was able to get the setup file to execute.  When I ran the example quikstart program I go the following errors:
>>> %Run tsl2591Quickstart.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "Quickstart.py", line 4, in <module>
tsl = tsl2591.Tsl2591()  # initialize
File "/tsl2591/tsl2591/read_tsl.py", line 70, in __init__self.set_timing(self.integration_time)
File "/tsl2591/tsl2591/read_tsl.py", line 75, in set_timing self.enable()
File "tsl2591/tsl2591/read_tsl.py", line 143, in enable    ENABLE_POWERON | ENABLE_AEN | ENABLE_AIEN
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O eror

Comment: Also I did install the adafruit blinka compatibility layer, but in what specific folder do I put the adafruit -Tsl2591 module so a python program can find it.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you use `maxlklaxl/python-tsl2591`, you *don't need* blinka. Just use `setup.py` from the `python-tsl2591` to install it.